# Arduino with Bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno

HI I am a newbie and need some suggestions 
Is there a possibility to do this?? I am trying to send MIDI data through a button using Arduino and bluetooth module HM10. Can someone help me write the loop part or am going the right way.

```
#include <MIDI.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial (2, 3);
char c = ' ';
int pushButton7 = 7;
int buttonState7 = 0;
int note7 = 0;
void setup() {
  MIDI.begin(4);
  // 115200 hairless MIDI
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pushButton7, INPUT);
}

  void loop() {

   int buttonState7 = digitalRead(pushButton7);



 // Button 7

  // when button pressed:
  if (buttonState7 == HIGH) {
    // if note not playing
    if (note7 == 0) {
      // play note (note number, velocity, channel)
      // more info: http://arduinomidilib.sourceforge.net/a00001.html
      // MIDI notes chart http://www.phys.unsw.edu.au/jw/notes.html
      // 55 = G3, 127 = trigger note with max volume
      MIDI.sendNoteOn(55,127,1);
      // note is playing
      note7 = 1;
    }
  // when button released
  } else {
    // if note playing
    if (note7 == 1) {
      // if playing - stop
      MIDI.sendNoteOff(55,0,1);
    }
    // if button released note is off
    note7 = 0;
  }

  delay(1);

  }
```